# Database viewer for CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am searching for CouchDB user interface like MySQL database has workbench so that I can create database, execute quires if exists How do I view existing databases using database viewer?

Answer (score 4):

CouchDB is NoSQL, so there are no tables nor queries but it comes with an included web interface called `futon`.

You can access it at the addess: http://yourdatabase:port/_utils

For instance, for a local install: http://localhost:5984/_utils

That being said, a CouchDB instance is composed of various databases which contain documents that you can only access by primary key.

More complicated queries can only be done by using the map-reduce pattern (you can list, edit and consult them from futon).